# PHP RESTful API How to obtain /details in resource

Tags: php, api, rest

I'm looking for best aproach in design of RESTful API based on doctrine2.

**EXAMPLE**

I've got two example tables. Product and ProductAttribiute (one-to-many relation)

When I make request like /products I can see list of products without attribiutes.

When I make request like /products/details I would like to see list of products with sub-resource attribiutes attached to each product.

I wonder is it better to make separate action (with separete query) or use the same query  and same DataProvider as /products action and to put some kind of join to /product-attribiutes resource.

**QUESTION**

General question is „Do you use same query for /products and /products/details action?”

Comment: Is the result data set the same? No. So no, you won't use the same query...

Answer (score 0):

Generally, a call to `/products` should return ALL the related data fields for that product (details/inventory/cost, etc). Where a call to `/products/details` should ONLY show the details field for that product.

Answer (score 0):

As far as the RESTful API design goes, one possible solution would be to have `details` as an optional parameter to `/products`. With this solution, a query of /products would return just the list without attributes, while a query of `/products?details=true` would return the list with all the details populated.

Another possibility is to implement an `expand` or `embed` query parameter which can be used to specify which specific fields should be expanded. For example, querying `/products?expand=company,shipping_info` would expand both the `company` and `shipping_info` resources. This is in line with the recommendation from this guide: http://www.vinaysahni.com/best-practices-for-a-pragmatic-restful-api#autoloading